# column not allowed here oracle with getText

Tags: java, sql, oracle, netbeans

I tried to save / edit / delete a new row in the database. writing in the gui values to be saved with getText ()

here is the code

```
Connection conn = Connessione.ConnecrDb();
   Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet emps = null;

   try{


   String sql;  
        sql = "INSERT INTO PROGETTO.LIBRO (ISBN, DISPONIBILITA, TITOLO, CASA_EDITRICE, CODICE_AUTORE, GENERE, PREZZO)"
                + "VALUES (txt_isbn, txt_disp, txt_titolo, txt_casa, txt_autore, txt_genere, txt_prezzo)";


        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        emps = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    String ISBN= txt_isbn.getText();
    String DISPONIBILITA= txt_disp.getText();
    String TITOLO= txt_titolo.getText();
    String CASA_EDITRICE= txt_casa.getText();
    String CODICE_AUTORE= txt_autore.getText();
    String GENERE= txt_genere.getText();
    String PREZZO = txt_prezzo.getText();


           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SALVATO");



               }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e)
   {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }
   finally 
   {
       try{
           if (emps != null)
                emps.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) { }
        try
        {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) { }
    }
```

Getting this error: column not allowed here

Above code just takes care of insert operation. How can I delete and modify table record?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: And what are these variables? `txt_isbn, txt_disp, txt_titolo, ...`?

Comment: i assume you are trying to insert values before assigning them to variables.

you need to put your assign statements and then use them in the insert query and execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO PROGETTO.LIBRO (ISBN, DISPONIBILITA, TITOLO, "
        + "CASA_EDITRICE, CODICE_AUTORE, GENERE, PREZZO)"
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {

    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);
    String ISBN = txt_isbn.getText();
    String DISPONIBILITA = txt_disp.getText();
    String TITOLO = txt_titolo.getText();
    String CASA_EDITRICE = txt_casa.getText();
    String CODICE_AUTORE = txt_autore.getText();
    String GENERE = txt_genere.getText();
    BigDecimal PREZZO = new BigDecimal(
            numberFormat.parse(txt_prezzo.getText()).doubleValue())
           .setScale(2);
    stmt.setString(1, ISBN);
    stmt.setString(2, DISPONIBILITA);
    stmt.setString(3, TITOLO);
    stmt.setString(4, CASA_EDITRICE);
    stmt.setString(5, CODICE_AUTORE);
    stmt.setString(6, GENERE);
    stmt.setBigDecimal(7, PREZZO);

    int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SALVATO");
} catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Try-with-resources closes the stmt automatically.

The prepared statement replaces the value in the SQL with something like:

```
INSERT INTO table(column1, colum2, ....)
VALUES('De\'l Rey',
       1234.50,
       ...)
```

for:

```
 "De'l Rey"
 1.234,50
```

updateCount should be 1 on success.

Comment: I use String for the price. work. I had tried to use float but don't work

Answer (score 1):

You have asked 2 different questions here

**1. Column not allowed here**

This happened because you have not passed values for any of parameter into insert statement.

I am not sure about your requirement however I will use PreparedStatement for this scenario.

Example

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
        + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "MindPeace");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
        preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

**2. This code is only to save the data, delete, and modify an entire row how can I do?**

Answer is very simple. You have to write code for the same :)

You need 3 SQL statement which has DELETE and UPDATE operation just like insert in above example.

Answer (score 0):

Wooow..true!!

I created three buttons to delete / update / insert and now it all works and automatically updates the tables.

you've been very very great. Thank you very much.

one last thing.

if I wanted to insert an error message when I delete / update etc "book not found" I tried to create an if:

```
Boolean found = false;
  try{
    sql= delete...... 
       etc
   if (!found)
```

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NOT FOUND","ERRORE",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

etc...

```
 Connection conn = Connessione.ConnecrDb();
   Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet emps = null;


    try{

        String sql= "DELETE FROM progetto.libro WHERE isbn =?";  /

        pst=(OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString (1, txt_isbn.getText());

        pst.execute();



         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ELIMINATO");
         Update_table(); 

         txt_isbn.setText("");
         txt_disp.setText("");
         txt_titolo.setText("");
         txt_casa.setText("");
         txt_autore.setText("");
         txt_genere.setText("");
         txt_prezzo.setText("");


    }


    catch (Exception e)
     {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);


    }
```

if you find the book must exit the book removed, or "not found". but as I deployed I always come out "deleted". why?

thanks again